# how can I play a game that isn't in the origin store?

Tags: origin, fifa-12, fifa-14

I bought FIFA 12 two years ago on Amazon, as a disc. When I installed it, it went through Origin, and now I play the game with Origin. Now I want to get FIFA 13 or 14, and they don't show up on the Origin store. I found [this](https://www.g2a.com/fifa-14-origin-key-global-i10000043109004?aid=10651989&___store=englishus&___currency=USD&er=d09a2df3f46d701692f0a2f80531db9b&mp=1&adid=GMC_USA&id=14&gclid=Cj0KCQiA_5_QBRC9ARIsADVww14O8gXhdZp38oSswuJfWsxdo4bVEFdePhMcr90LyhY1rRmOKp1f0uEaAnz9EALw_wcB) that offers a FIFA 14 Origin key, but if the game isn't in the Origin store, can I still download it?

I've noticed that when I want to reinstall my copy of FIFA 12 I can just redownload it from Origin, so presumably it's somewhere in the cloud. Does that mean that FIFA 14 is also still around, but Origin just doesn't offer it in their store anymore?

Comment: I believe EA simply discontinue their games since they'd rather you buy the newer one instead. It's likely you will still be able to run this game, but probably no multiplayer (EA would've shut down servers). Then again, I wouldn't be surprised if you simply cannot play the game through Origin anymore.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Would it be worth it to buy the code?

Comment: I wouldn't without a LOT of research of people saying the game still works. Presumably anyone who owned the game beforehand can still play it, so I don't see why you wouldn't be able to, but with EA involved I feel it's best to just play it safe. Unfortunately I'm just guessing, which is why I haven't written an answer, because truly I just don't know.